# Insert values two dependent tables Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I've created a query out of 3 dependent tables:

1. car parts(id, name, value);
2. car_model(id, name,price);
3. part_and_model(car_model_id, car_part_id)

I get my car models from a list of values, and for car_id I use sequence for increment.

I have all the needed fields from my query, but now I want to insert data into car_parts and part_and_model at the same time. I've created two processes on submit to insert (the first for car_parts(fk) and the second for part_and_model). When I run this, I get this error and no data gets inserted into the tables:

ORA-02291: integrity constraint (PRACTICE.FK_CAR_PART_car_part) violated - parent key not found

When I delete the second process, the data is correctly inserted into the car_parts table. Why is this happening? Does the second process execute before first? What else am I missing?

item P8_CAR_MODEL = LOV;
item P8_ID=>sequence: SELECT CP_SEK.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;

process1:insert into CAR_PARTS(CP_ID,CP_NAME,CP_PRICE) VALUES (:P8_ID, :P8_NAME, :P8_PRICE);

process2: insert into part_and_model(PART_ID, MODEL_ID) values (:P8_ID,:P8_CAR_MODEL);

EDIT:

I managed to insert into car_parts table, but the error still says that the parent cannot be found (even though) it's in the table, so it must be the sequence...
here is my code:
process1:
begin 
select PART_SEK.NEXTVAL INTO :P8_ID from dual;

insert into car_parts(id,name,value) VALUES (:P8_ID, :P8_NAME, :P8_PRICE);
end;

process2:

insert into part_and_model(car_model_id, car_part_id) values (:P8_MODEL,:P8_ID);

EDIT2:
when i use PART_SEK.currval instead of p8_id in second process, it works
Once again, thank you all for your time.

Comment: As littlefoot said, do both the inserts in a single process. But I had one comment I wanted to add. If you don't really need the item P8_ID to be viewed before the insert(which you most likely don't), you should declare it and assign it its value in the process just before inserting. Because if its the source of an item, every time you load, the sequence triggers. So your DB will have gaps in the CP_ID(values going like 1, 3, 4, 8, 13,..) This doesn't really break anything, it's just nicer if they are perfectly sequential.

Answer (score 1):

Insert rows into both tables in the same process; master table first, details next.

Comment: @marcus Whats the constraint PRACTICE.FK_CAR_PART_car_part

Comment: In the table part and model, i have two foreign keys, car part id (referencing car parts id) and model id (referencing  one from the model table)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sequence of the processes. The first process must have a lower sequence e.g 10 and the second must be greater.
Be sure that you in the first process you have to insert into the master table.
Change the processes execution point to processing.

Comment: First process has lower sequence (10), and second 20. I also added code to get seq.nextval to page  item in the first process. 

Insert into car parts is now successful, but still says no foreign key (the one that's just been inserted) for when the second process executes. Thanks to all of you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
  a_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  a_id := your_sequence.nextval;

  INSERT INTO car_parts (cp_id, cp_name, cp_price)
  VALUES (a_id, :P8_NAME, :P8_PRICE);

  INSERT INTO part_and_model (part_id, model_id)
  VALUES (a_id, :P8_CAR_MODEL);
END;
```

By all rights this should work. I do believe your problem really is with the sequence, nothing else I can think of that would cause your error. So please try this and let us know.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, unfortunately, it didn't work.

I managed to insert into car_parts table, but the error still says that the parent cannot be found (even though) it's in the table, so it must be the sequence...
here is my code:
process1:
begin 
select PART_SEK.NEXTVAL INTO :P8_ID from dual;

insert into car_parts(id,name,value) VALUES (:P8_ID, :P8_NAME, :P8_PRICE);
end;

process2:

insert into part_and_model(car_model_id, car_part_id) values (:P8_MODEL,:P4_ID_PRICE);

Comment: @marcus now thats some new code, the second insert takes :P4_ID_PRICE??
Have you tried the procedure I wrote with just the necessary variable name changes?
If nothing still works, go into Object browser and find the id of a previously entered car part and insert just that as a static value, so we see if perhaps your foreign key is messed up.

Comment: p4_id_price was my mistake, when i copied. i use sequence currval, and it works now, thanks alot.